# Is it possible to prevent property changes of an object from triggering didSet{} in Swift/Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, key-value-observing

I have an object bound to a controller as shown below:

```
// ViewController

@objc dynamic var objectX: SomeClass {
   didSet {
      print("something")
   }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
   self.bind(NSBindingName(rawValue: "objectX"),
                      to: controller,
                      withKeyPath: "selectedObject",
                      options: nil)
}
```

An I expect didSet{} to be called if the controller has a different object selected.  However if one of the properties of objectX gets changed then didSet{} is also getting called.

Surely this shouldn't be occurring - and if this is expected then is there any way to prevent property changes on the object itself from triggering the didSet{} or is it necessary to check in the didSet{} whether the object is a different one to the old one?

This is a bit odd because when I test in a Playground changing a property on the object does not trigger the didSet{} callback.

Comment: If named `SomeClass` is not a struct then didSet should not be called, as you confirmed tested for Playground (probably on simplified demo). So it is supposed that the reason is some different code. Would you provide minimal reproducible code?

Comment: SomeClass is a protocol - and the property being changed is one defined by the protocol.  Changing the native backing property does not trigger didSet{}.  Seems to behave differently in a Playground so have yet to reproduce this